# Can't create user in IAM it says "No Identity-based policy allows the iam:CreateUser action"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm New to AWS and trying to create a user with access rights to the RDS but not to the EC2 and vice versa however, i'm constantly getting this error when i try to create a user in IAM.
Error "User was not created.
User: arn:aws:sts::108692552088:assumed-role/voclabs/user2795395=30410182 is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateUser on resource: arn:aws:iam::108692552088:user/hwma because no identity-based policy allows the iam:CreateUser action"
How do i fix this error?

I've tried to creating a custom policy with this JSON`{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": "iam:CreateUser", "Resource": "*" } ] }`but no solved

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to create users in AWS Academy accounts.